# The problem with Internationalization in Spring Boot do not work in Configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm currently working on a Web-App using Spring boot (including spring security). At the moment i'm trying to integrate internationalization support for the defult language russian as a start.
This is a configuration file where I write to get messages in the Russian language, if the user writed wrong data or e.t but this code returns me In English

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration

public class ConfigForAuth {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rs.addBasenames("classpath:i18n/messages");
        rs.addBasenames("classpath:/org/springframework/security/messages_ru.properties:1");
        rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return rs;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");

        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }
}
```

But if I will write this same code in Application file this code works fine and returns to me in RU
Application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("--.--.--")//conf
@EnableCaching
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:clients.properties")
})
public class OneBpmAuthApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OneBpmAuthApiApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think previous advice was more or less right just you need to set ParamName to "lang" like so:

```
   @Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new
            LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

also please do remember to extend WebMvcConfigurer.

Comment: I also tried like this but is not worked. I do not why this not work but works in the application file

Comment: try sending a get request to localhost with `?lang=ru` like so: `localhost:8080?lang=ru`

Comment: yes, but if you need to change it manually, but I want it to be in Russian by default

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the problem is in the default setting and that interceptor works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and adding the interceptors.

```java
@Configuration
public class ConfigForAuth extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```